# Cython module doesn't work

Tags: python, cython

I'm trying to produce a simple fibonacci algorithm with Cython.
I have fib.pyx:

```
def fib(int n):
    cdef int i
    cdef double a=0.0, b=1.0
    for i in range(n):
        a, b = a + b, a
    return a
```

and setup.py in the same folder:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules=cythonize('fib.pyx'))
```

Then I open cmd and cd my way to this folder and build the code with (I have [http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266](this compiler) :

```
python setup.py build
```

Which produces this result:

```
C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\Python Scripts\Cython>python setup.py build
Compiling fib.pyx because it changed.
Cythonizing fib.pyx
running build
running build_ext
building 'fib' extension
creating build
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
C:\Anaconda\Scripts\gcc.bat -DMS_WIN64 -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Anaconda\include -IC:
\Anaconda\PC -c fib.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\fib.o
writing build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\fib.def
creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
C:\Anaconda\Scripts\gcc.bat -DMS_WIN64 -shared -s build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Relea
se\fib.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\fib.def -LC:\Anaconda\libs -LC:\Anacon
da\PCbuild\amd64 -lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\fib.pyd
```

So it seems the compiling worked and I should be able to import this module with

```
import fib
ImportError: No module named fib
```

Where did I go wrong?
Edit:

```
os.getcwd()
Out[6]: 'C:\\Users\\MyUserName\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\Cython\\build\\temp.win-amd64-2.7\\Release'

In [7]: import fib
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-6c0ab2f0a4e0>", line 1, in <module>
    import fib

ImportError: No module named fib
```

Comment: Where's the file? What's your working directory?

Comment: I tried to change working directory in python to `C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\Python Scripts\Cython\build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release` where is fib.def and fib.o and import fib but it didn't work either..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiling worked however the library was placed under: `build\lib.win-amd64-2.7` so you have to either copy/move the file in the current directory or change your current directory to that one.

You can see this in the last part of the command run:

```
-o build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\fib.pyd
```

The `-o` option stands for *output* and specifies where it should put the final compiled file.

Comment: Thanks alot. I thought for some reason the temp folder that contained the fib.o was the module... Thanks for fast response.

Answer (score 6):

Use
python setup.py build_ext **--inplace**

--inplace flag will put your pyd in the working directory